# Rails fragment caching slower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm trying to implement fragment caching in Rails. Without caching, code looks like this:

```
<div>
  <% data = MyObject.getDataFromDataBase %>

  <!-- complicated divs displaying the 'data', multiple partials -->
</div>
```

It creates a lot of SQL queries (in the view) and, in overall, takes around:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1107ms (Views: 1007.0ms | ActiveRecord: 93.6ms)
```

After wrapping this up with cache like this:

```
<div>
  <% cache 'my_cached' do %>
    <% data = MyObject.getDataFromDataBase %>

    <!-- complicated divs displaying the 'data', multiple partials -->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I see the output (on the second refresh) - NO SQL queries (besides user role check), nothing, just:

```
 Read fragment views/my_cached/bda6867d8a08ec1637c0c926edced2d2 (0.7ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 1241ms (Views: 1228.7ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
```

And my questions is: **How its possible, that AFTER caching it takes longer?** Nothing happens in the logs, file is loaded in 0.7 ms, why it takes over 1 second overall?

Comment: Seems like you are missing a `do`: `<% cache 'my_cached' do %>`

Comment: Yeah, mistake in writing the question.

Comment: In https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35257 Aaron pointed out that partial caching is very slow when the partial is very small.

Answer (score 0):

Caching works correctly.

I've used [mini profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) to see how rendering works and my page refreshes faster - from 160 ms to around 10 ms. The problem was **development** mode and **application.html.erb** file, with loading time around 1 second.